# Save a DOM element to posterior use in another page (Chrome Extension)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to save a DOM node to posterior insert it in another page of same website.

I am using jQuery with my extension. What I did in content_script.js was:

```
var variableToStore = localStorage["variableToStore"];

if (variableToStore == null) {
    localStorage["variableToStore"] = jQuery("#myDomNode").clone();
    variableToStore = localStorage["variableToStore"];
}

variableToStore.insertAfter(jQuery("#someelementofanotherpage"));
```

What I am doing wrong? localStorage cannot save DOM objects? If not, how can I achieve my objective?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid it would save only the children of myDomNode

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, no you cannot store DOM elements in local storage. Even with jStorage plugin, you cannot store DOM elements in local storage as stated in the intro text: http://www.jstorage.info/

You can store an HTML-encoded string for JavaScript in local storage, then convert it back to html after (refer to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding) for help in that area)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @BumbleB2na! I encode the html string, stored it, and retrieve the html with success!

Answer (score 1):

You may save a string with the html code instead, try this:

```
var div=$('<div></div>');
$("#myDomNode").clone().appendTo(div);
localStorage["variableToStore"] = escape(div.html());
...
var variableToStore = unescape(localStorage["variableToStore"]);
$(variableToStore).appendTo($("#someelementofanotherpage"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, @Francois. Your idea of include the desired html inside the div to correctly retrieve the full html was excellent. 
I just had to encode the html to storage works. I used the "escape()" function of javascrip to store properly, and "unescape()" after read it.

Answer (score 1):

Francois' solution works, however clone() doesn't reflect JQuery modifications, so I had to run this before:

```
$("input").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});
```

I use overall for storing state of form with jStorage.

(I don't have enough reputation to comment, sorry)

Comment: Not having enough reputation to comment is not, in general, a reason to answer instead; but in your case it works as an answer.